# Finding the most specific class in Java

Tags: java, reflection, instanceof

I tried to write some kind of exception handler for my specific purposes.
I have a list of classes. Let's say:

```
List<Class<? extends Throwable>> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(RuntimeException.class);
list.add(IllegalArgumentException.class);
```

Now, I want to do:

```
public Class<? extends Throwable> findMostSpecific(Class<? extends Throwable> type) {
     for (....) {
         if (... WHAT TO PUT HERE ? .... ) {
             return ....
         }
     }
}
```

this method has to find the most specific class of given type. So if I pass:

- IllegalArgumentException, it has to find IllegalArgumentException (not RTE).
- RuntimeException, it has to find RuntimeException
- IllegalStateException, it has to find also RuntimeException (becuse IllegalStateException is not on the list)
- if I add `CustomException extends IllegalArgumentException` and pass it, it has to return IllegalArgumentException (not RTE and CustomException is not on the list, so IllegalArgumentException is the most specific)

So how to find the most specific type of a given instance? Is it possible?

Comment: Just work with the representing **class object**. Access it by `type.class`, then you can use methods like `Class#getName` and stuff like that. From there you can also check stuff like `Class#isInstance(Object o)` or call methods or create instances using constructors and so on. Here is the [Java-Doc of Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). Note that this class object will always work on the *real* class, not a restricted view. So you directly receive what you are searching for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving it a shot here:

```
public Class<? extends Throwable> findMostSpecific(Class<? extends Throwable> type) {
     // we'll keep a reference to the most specific one here
     Class<? extends Throwable> mostSpecific = null;
     // here we iterate over your list of types
     for (Class<? extends Throwable> tType : list) {
         // well not even a subtype of tType so ignore it
         if (!tType.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
             continue;
         }

         if (mostSpecific == null || mostSpecific.isAssignableFrom(tType)) {
             mostSpecific = tType;
         }
     }
     return mostSpecific;
}
```

Comment: I've added one more requirement to the original question. I'll have to check if it'll work in such case in a moment

Comment: You mean your custom class? Should still work, since your custom class is not in the list and `IllegalArgumentException` is more specific than `RuntimeException`.

Comment: It works. The second answer also works but Because you was the first who replied I'll accept yours

Answer (score 3):

A stream-based solution could also consist of two simple steps:

- filtering the stream based on whether the elements are assignable from the given class
- computing the maximum of the remaining stream

As shown here:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MostSpecificClassFinder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Class<?>> classes = Arrays.asList(
            RuntimeException.class, 
            IllegalArgumentException.class
        );

        System.out.println(findMostSpecific(classes, IllegalArgumentException.class));
        System.out.println(findMostSpecific(classes, RuntimeException.class));
        System.out.println(findMostSpecific(classes, IllegalStateException.class));
        System.out.println(findMostSpecific(classes, CustomException.class));
    }

    public static Class<?> findMostSpecific(List<Class<?>> classes, Class<?> type) {
        return classes.stream()
            .filter(c -> c.isAssignableFrom(type))
            .max((c0, c1) -> c0.isAssignableFrom(c1) ? -1 : c1.isAssignableFrom(c0) ? 1 : 0)
            .get();
    }

}

class CustomException extends IllegalArgumentException 
{

}
```

Comment: Very nice, but do you think is it somehow better than previous examples? Just asking :)

Comment: @Mariusz.v7 Admittedly, I find the current stream-based solution ... "a bit odd", to say the least: I don't see a reason for comparing the classes by their `getCanonicalName`. Beyond that, ending the stream with a **recursive call** that again operates on a stream looks bizarre...

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use `Class.getCanonicalName()` to detect current class at the runtime. Consider following example test case that uses Java Stream API to found the best candidate:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class ReflectionTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        assertThat(findMostSpecific(IllegalArgumentException.class)).isEqualTo(IllegalArgumentException.class);

        assertThat(findMostSpecific(RuntimeException.class)).isEqualTo(RuntimeException.class);

        assertThat(findMostSpecific(IllegalStateException.class)).isEqualTo(RuntimeException.class);

        assertThat(findMostSpecific(IllegalStateException.class)).isEqualTo(RuntimeException.class);

        assertThat(findMostSpecific(CustomException.class)).isEqualTo(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    }

    public Class<? extends Throwable> findMostSpecific(Class<? extends Throwable> type) {
        List<Class<? extends Throwable>> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(RuntimeException.class);
        list.add(IllegalArgumentException.class);

        return list.stream()
                .peek(e -> System.out.println("e.getClass() == " + e.getClass()))
                .filter(e -> type.getCanonicalName().equals(e.getCanonicalName()))
                .findAny()
                .orElseGet(() -> findMostSpecific((Class<? extends Throwable>) type.getSuperclass()));
    }

    public static class CustomException extends IllegalArgumentException {}
}
```

I've added `.peek(e -> System.out.println("e.getClass() == " + e.getClass()))` on purpose so you can see that here we get compile-time information:

```
e.getClass() == class java.lang.Class
e.getClass() == class java.lang.Class
e.getClass() == class java.lang.Class
```

`Class.getCanonicalName()` from the other hand returns a canonical name of a run-time class. `.orElseGet()` uses check for most specific class using parent class name, so for `IllegalStateException.class` you will get `RuntimeException.class` as expected. Of course this is just a exemplary code that could be polished and improved (e.g. list with classes should not be instantiated for every method call). I hope it helps.

Comment: Nice try, I've added one requirement to the original question, I think it will not work in such case. I'll try in a moment.

Comment: It will work exactly as you expect - if class is not found then `findMostSpecific` is called for a parent class. So `CustomException` will return `IllegalArgumentException` and not `RuntimeException`. I've updated code sample.

Comment: Both answers work. It's a pity that I cannot accept both of them. Michael Rose was quicker so I'll accept his answer. And +1 for you. Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason to compare by `getCanonicalName` and not the class instances directly?

Comment: Comparing canonical names is not a good way to compare classes at runtime. Some classes don't even have canonical names (anonymous, local) and `getCanonicalName()` returns `null` and it's even possible to have two classes loaded by different class loaders which have the same name.